# How can I get the updated variable value in other methods in python?

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance

I have this issue: I am getting the default value I set for self.balance instead of the current one with all the deposits and witdrawls..
This output:

```
Your interest rate is 0.05 and balance 500. Total calculated is 25.0.
```

Is suposed to be:

```
Your interest rate is 0.05 and balance 800. Total calculated is 40.0.
```

I am not sure how can I accomplish this, it works fine for the rest like the calculate_credit() method I did the same I don't understand why the credit method is pulling the updated self.balance but not the interest_rate one..

FULL CODE:

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self, account_number, balance):
        self.account_number = account_number
        self.balance = balance

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount
        return f'Your new balance is {self.balance}, you deposited {amount}.'

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        self.balance -= amount
        return f'Your new balance is {self.balance}, you withdrew {amount}.'

    def get_balance(self):
        return f'Your current balance is {self.balance}'


class SavingsAccount(Account):
    def __init__(self, account_number, balance, interest_rate):
        super().__init__(account_number, balance)
        self.interest_rate = interest_rate

    def calculate_interest(self):
        interest_rate_calculation = self.balance * self.interest_rate
        return f'Your interest rate is {self.interest_rate} and balance {self.balance}. Total calculated is {interest_rate_calculation}.'


class BusinessAccount(Account):
    def __init__(self, account_number, balance, credit_req):
        super().__init__(account_number, balance)
        self.credit_req = credit_req

    def calculate_credit(self):
        if self.balance > 0.10 * self.credit_req:
            print(f'Credit approved. You now have {self.credit_req} in your bank account.')
            self.balance += self.credit_req
        else:
            print(f'You need to have at least 10% of the credit amount.')


accountX = Account(5, 500)
accountX_interest = SavingsAccount(5, accountX.balance, 0.05)
deposit = accountX.deposit(500)
withdraw = accountX.withdraw(200)
credit_request = BusinessAccount("CZ50", accountX.balance, 5000)

print(deposit)
print(withdraw)
print(accountX.get_balance())
print(accountX_interest.calculate_interest())
print(credit_request.calculate_credit())
print(credit_request.get_balance())
```

Comment: Why do you expect a value of `800`? You set the value during creation of the object with `accountX_interest = SavingsAccount(5, accountX.balance, 0.05)` and never change it afterwards. But the code is strange anyway. Why don't you use only one `Account` class with the appropriate methods?

Comment: I got it!
You said "You set the value during creation of the object with accountX_interest = SavingsAccount(5, accountX.balance, 0.05) and never change it afterwards."

I figured the code was before the changes hapenned so naturally it will be the same value.. Rookie mistake i think.

I just put the line: 
accountX_interest = SavingsAccount(5, accountX.balance, 0.05)

In front of the account movements like deposit withdraw etc and it worked properly, thank you Matthias.

I am learning OOP and Python still. Thank you for the help!